# How do I edit a bug in a Python 3 API that I have installed?

Tags: python, podio

I've installed the Podio API for Python 3 and found that it imports urlencode from urllib (from where you apparently would import it in Python 2), instead of urllib.parse (where it seems to be in Python 3), making me unable to do pretty much anything with the API. When I edit the code nothing happens and I'm assuming it's because I've already installed it, so how would I go about fixing that? I've looked around but didn't really find any clear instructions on how to do this.

Comment: You're obviously using a version not compatible with Python 3. There will probably be more issues than just that one. See https://github.com/podio/podio-py/issues/41

Comment: I reinstalled by typing: pip install -e git+https://github.com/podio/podio-py.git#egg=podio-py and now I'm getting a new error that I wrote in another answer

Comment: Don't write new errors in answers. This isn't a continuous forum thread.

Comment: So where am I supposed to type it?

Comment: In this case it looks like you have a new question and should open a new question.

Comment: Uhm ok, seems like that will just make it more difficult for people with the same issue finding this post, but ok.

Comment: Updating your question is fine too, but since this seems like a completely different issue which would invalidate the already given answer, it does not belong here.

Answer (score 3):

The podio library for python available on pip doesn't seems to be up to date. The last version from github seem to fix your bug.

You should install it as it is recommanded on the project  [readme](https://github.com/podio/podio-py):

> pip install -e git+https://github.com/podio/podio-py.git#egg=podio-py

(See [this issue](https://github.com/podio/podio-py/issues/41))

If it doesn't fix your bug, you should fix it on github and make a pull request. This way you will still be able to upgrade it if there is updates later.

Comment: Hmm, alright, not sure if that isn't what I did when I installed it a couple of days ago. I'm very new to programming and had some issues, don't remember which method of installing eventually worked. Anyway, I installed it again now by just typing

> pip install -e git+https://github.com/podio/podio-py.git#egg=podio-py

in the CMD

Comment: Where can I find the .py-files now? The init.py, api.py, transport.py etc. I can't find them in site-packages.